Log in ActiveMQ Artemis web console from Docker
I try to use the ActiveMQ Artemis console from web. I run it in docker. What pass and login I need to use by default?
  artemis:
    image: vromero/activemq-artemis:2.6.1
    container_name: artemis
    ports:
      - "8161:8161"
      - "61616:61616"
    environment:
      ACTIVEMQ_NAME: activemq
      ACTIVEMQ_USERNAME: admin
      ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD: password

I add environment, but it not help to log in to the web console.
I try to using all default login/pass like:
root root, admin-admin, and etc.

ARTEMIS_USER
The administrator username. The default is artemis.
ARTEMIS_PASSWORD
The administrator password. The default is artemis.

You're using vromero/activemq-artemis:2.6.1 which is has a couple of problems:

It is over 3 years old at this point.
vromero/activemq-artemis is archived. It specifically says, "Deprecated. Don't use."

I recommend you use an official Apache ActiveMQ Artemis image. Documentation is available here which states:

Once the broker starts you can open the web management console at http://localhost:8161 and log in with the default username & password artemis.


I changed my image and version, but still cannot login in webConsole, in documentation i see "A login screen will be presented, if your broker is secure, you will need to use a user with admin
role, if it is unsecure simply enter any user/password."  any p user/pass- Invalid login credentials

I updated my answer with the specific text from the documentation which indicates what the default username and password is for the official Docker image. Hope that helps!
